# Shortest path algorithm for URLs

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am having trouble with finding a shortest path between two URLs.  A .csv that we are provided lists a bunch of websites seperated by commas.  Each website can access the next website within a hyperlink on that page.  For example if the file reads espn.com , espn.com/nba , espn.com/nbaschedules you can go from espn.com to the nba page, and from the nba page to the nba schedules.  My job is to find the least number of clicks to get from one website to the other.  Here is how I have stored the file so far.  What I am using is the STL unordered_map for storage.

```
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
inFile.open("urls.csv");
string line;
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> urlAdjList;
while(getline(inFile, line))  //Reads each line one at a time.
{
    int firstWord = 0;
    istringstream iss(line);
    string firstURL, url;
    while(iss >> url)
    {
        if(firstWord == 0 && url != "|")
        {
            firstURL = url;
            urlAdjList[firstURL];
            firstWord = 1;
                outFile << firstURL << endl;
        }
        else
            urlAdjList[firstURL].push_back(url);
    }
}
//Find the shortest path between mURL and nURL?
```

My question is did I store it correctly?  Would I need to use Dijkstra's algorithm or breadth-first search?

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algo is efficient only if the cost of switching between hyperlinks are different.

So prefer BFS.

O(V) is better than O ((V+E)log(V+E)) {V-vertices, E-edges}

It's better to store the graph in an adjacency list of ids using vector< vector < int > > rather than storing it in vector< vector < string > >. Use an array to identify the URL of an id.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use Dijkstra's algorithm for this. You'll also need to store all your data in some kind of graph structure, eg.

```
struct graph_node {
    vector<graph_node*> neighbours;
    string url;
}
```

You could also use a map to then store all the value->graph_node pointers. Then use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path after you've built up the graph.